# Couldn't validate email on client side

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the class below and the default scaffold view, but I am unable to validate email on client side. I also tried another email regular expression but that didn't work either. What am I missing here?

```
public class Person
{
    [Email(ErrorMessage="...........")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
{
    public EmailAttribute()
        : base(@"^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That regex rejects many valid email addresses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might find the [following blog post](http://www.pagedesigners.co.nz/2011/02/asp-net-mvc-3-email-validation-with-unobtrusive-jquery-validation/) useful. Taken from it:

```
public class EmailAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public EmailAttribute()
        : base(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
               @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
               @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$")
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());
        yield return new EmailValidationRule(errorMessage);
    }
}

public class EmailValidationRule : ModelClientValidationRule
{
    public EmailValidationRule(string errorMessage)
    {
        ErrorMessage = errorMessage;
        ValidationType = "email";
    }
}
```

And the usage:

```
public class Person
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [Email(ErrorMessage = "{0} appears to be invalid.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And that's pretty much all. Because this custom attribute implements [IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable.aspx) the client validation will work as well.

And of course if the regular expression used in this example doesn't suits you don't hesitate to improve it.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, yeah, certainly, this regex could be improved.